# How to read the coordinates from the event.feature.getGeometry using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to read the coordinates from `event.feature.getGeometry()`. Here the event is an instance of `google.maps.Data.MouseEvent`.

When I log it like below:

```
console.log('output', event.feature.getGeometry);
```

it gives me an output like so:

[image]

I am not sure how to read the latitudes and longitudes for this. Could someone help me with this? I am using React and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.Geometry) you can loop over your lat/longs like so:

```
const geo = event.feature.getGeometry();

geo.forEachLatLng(latLng => {
    const lat = latLng.lat();
    const lng = latLng.lng();

    console.log(lat, lng);
});
```